# JSQMessagesViewController changedBubbleImage not working

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I try to change the default MessagesBubbleImage of JSQMessagesViewController by passing custom image into init method, but it's not working, here is the code

```
outgoingBubbleImageView = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory.init(bubbleImage: UIImage(named: "bubbleMine"), capInsets: UIEdgeInsetsZero).outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor.grayColor())
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had been working on your question but I had resolved on Objective C, so I will post my answer and a translation to Swift

On `DemoModelData` `Init`

```
JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory *bubbleFactory = [[JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory alloc] initWithBubbleImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleMine"] capInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero layoutDirection:UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft];

self.outgoingBubbleImageData = [bubbleFactory outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

Swift Translation

```
let bubbleFactory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory(bubbleImage: UIImage(named: "bubbleMine")!, capInsets: UIEdgeInsetsZero, layoutDirection: .RightToLeft)

self.outgoingBubbleImageData = bubbleFactory.outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor.grayColor())
self.incomingBubbleImageData = bubbleFactory.outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleGreenColor())
```

Note that the shape is what you get from this, not the color

I hope this helps you, for me works ok